# Add static text to TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm developing a custom `TextBox` for displaying and editing currency values. What I would like is to have a currency symbol visible within the `TextBox` on the left side. Overriding `OnPaint` of a `TextBox` is sort of horror after Googling and doing some tests. Anybody have other ideas? Maybe add the symbol as a background picture to the `TextBox` (if that is rather simple)?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you put a label before the text box and display the currency value?

Comment: You could probably overlay the label, and as long as it doesn't completely cover the `TextBox` the `TextBox` will still receive click events.

Comment: Because I think it looks better and you don't need to add an extra label just for the symbol. Yuck's option is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

why not just:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!textBox1.Text.StartsWith("£"))
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Concat("£", textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do several things:

- Add a "$" in your get property of the textbox
- Add a label with a static $
- Create a user control with a $ as a label and reuse it with your custom textbox

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a watermark in your textbox--please see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/WaterMark.aspx) for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MaskedTextBox instead of a TextBox. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

For your Mask property, use "$" for the currency symbol.